# I am trying to add scope of serilog logger in ASP.NET Core with Angular application but serilog scope is not working

Tags: angular, .net-core, serilog

Please help me out how to add Serilog logs in Visual Studio 2022 in `program.cs`.

I am trying to add scope of serilog logger in an ASP.NET Core with Angular application but serilog scope is not working, and the logs are not generated.

```
.Enrich.WithProperty("Application", "CMS_CORE_NG")
.Enrich.WithProperty("MachineName", Environment.MachineName)
.Enrich.WithProperty("CurrentManagedThreadId", Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId)
.Enrich.WithProperty("OSVersion", Environment.OSVersion)
.Enrich.WithProperty("Version", Environment.Version)
.Enrich.WithProperty("UserName", Environment.UserName)
.Enrich.WithProperty("ProcessId", Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id)
.Enrich.WithProperty("ProcessName", Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName)

// .WriteTo.Console(theme: CustomConsoleTheme.VisualStudioMacLight)
.WriteTo.File(formatter: new CutomTextFormatter(), path: Path.Combine(hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath + $"{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}Logs{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}", $"cms_core_ng_{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMdd}.txt"))
.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration));

var host = Host.CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

    try
    {
        int zero = 0;
        int result = 100 / zero;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         Log.Error("An error occurred while seeding the database  {Error} {StackTrace} {InnerException} {Source}",
                   ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, ex.InnerException, ex.Source);
    }
}

host.Run();
```

This the scope I am trying to add in `program.cs` file:

```
using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

    try
    {
        int zero = 0;
        int result = 100 / zero;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error("An error occurred while seeding the database  {Error} {StackTrace} {InnerException} {Source}",
         ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, ex.InnerException, ex.Source);
    }
}

host.Run();
```

Comment: Install-Package Serilog
Install-Package Serilog.Sinks.Console
Install-Package Serilog.Sinks.File

Comment: all packages are installed

Answer (score 0):

This line creates DI scope: `host.Services.CreateScope`, logger scope is different:

```
public class LoggingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public LoggingMiddleware(
        RequestDelegate next,
        ILogger<LoggingMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var state = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            ["headers:MY_HEADER"] = httpContext.Request.Headers["MY_HEADER"].ToString(),
        };

        using (_logger.BeginScope(state))
        {
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use `LogContext.PushProperty`;